# mysql join query to extract ids which are blocking only CLOSED bugs

Tags: mysql, join

Tables bugs and dependencies looks like this:

```
select * from bugs; 
+--------+--------+
| bug_id | status |
+--------+--------+
|     20 | NEW    |
|     45 | CLOSED |
|     47 | NEW    |
|     30 | NEW    |
|     50 | CLOSED |
+--------+--------+


select * from dependencies;
+-----------+---------+
| dependson | blocked |
+-----------+---------+
|        20 |      45 |
|        20 |      47 |
|        30 |      50 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Expected result of join query: 30

What? Extract only 30 from column dependson, table dependencies because 30 is the only ( *NEW status* ) one which blocks ( col: blocked-50 ) a bug whose status is CLOSED. 
Although the dependson entry 20 is blocking 45 which is CLOSED but it also blocks 47 which is not CLOSED.

Note: Both the columns dependson and blocked are foreign key of bug_id.

I tried different queries but not able to get proper one still... Can anybody please help ?

Update: need status only NEW not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT b.* FROM bugs b
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      d.*
    FROM dependencies d
      JOIN bugs b
        ON b.bug_id = d.blocked
    GROUP BY d.dependson
      HAVING COUNT(IF(status = 'CLOSED', status, NULL)) = COUNT(*)
  ) t
  ON b.bug_id = t.dependson
```

Comment: Missed to specify, I need the 30 only when its status is NEW. How to do that ?

Comment: I managed to do this following select bug_id from bugs where bug_id in ( your query - d.dependson instead of d.* ) And bug_status = 'NEW'; - but this takes a lot of time to complete execution ..

Comment: Next fields should be indexed - bugs.bug_id, bugs.status, dependencies.dependson, dependencies.blocked.

Comment: It works fine now with this: Your query appended with ""And status='New';"" Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select bugs.* From bugs Inner Join dependencies On (bugs.bug_id = dependencies.blocked) Where bugs.status = 'CLOSED' And bugs.bug_id = dependencies.blocked
```

Really, you probably don't need the `and` part of that `where` statement, but I can't test it, so threw it in there for good measure.

**EDIT**

I just seen you are trying to get the dependson and not the blocked.  I'll update this.

```
Select bugs.bug_id From bugs Inner Join dependencies On (bugs.bug_id = dependencies.dependedson) 
  Where dependencies.dependson Not In 
    (Select dependencies.dependson From bugs Inner Join dependencies On (bugs.bug_id = dependencies.blocked) 
      Where bugs.status = 'New' And bugs.bug_id = dependencies.blocked) 
    And bugs.bug_id = dependencies.dependson
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not been tested but I don't think you're going to need a join here.

```
SELECT dependson 
FROM dependencies

WHERE dependson NOT IN
(SELECT bug_id FROM bugs WHERE status <> 'CLOSED')
```

This way you should get only `dependson`s which are CLOSED.